# Clarification on enabling the POS from API in Uber

Tags: uber-api

Small clarification on enabling POS from API in Uber. When we enable "pos_integration_enabled" Boolean integration will enable. I just want to know when we enable it what happened to the orders coming to the normal uber tab. is it going to stop or that is independent of POS integration.

Answer (score 0):

Got it from Uber support. POS integration is independent from Tab